# boolean not recorded in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an apps that load a json from a remote server, using a NSURLConnection. Once it has finished loading (calling connectionDidFinishLoading), I want to record if it was the first launch of the application.
So in connectionDidFinishLoading I did that :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL firstLaunch = [defaults boolForKey:@"screen_firstLaunch"];
NSLog(@"First launch : %d",firstLaunch);
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"screen_firstLaunch"];
```

And it displays "First launch : 0" every time ....

So I thought it might be because it's on another thread, so I try to deport the code into a function that I call in connectionDidFinishLoading using performSelectorOnMainThread, but I get the same result ...

Please someone help me, I'm going mad !

Comment: Oliver is right. You need to synchronize after you add something to userdefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to call `[defaults synchronize];` after setting your key in the defaults.

Comment: That's what I missed, thank you ! Although, I don't know why it has worked before without using this ...

Comment: @Julien : It's because the OS decide when to write if you do not force him. You may have been in a test case where the OS had decided to write the prefs.